# Insert different classes in alternate rows in struts2 datagrid

Tags: datagrid, struts2

i am using datagrids in struts2, i have almost done the integration and now i want to insert different classess in the alternate rows in the listing.

Here is my script

```
 <sjg:grid
        id="gridtable"
        dataType="json"
        href="%{remoteurl}"
        pager="true"
        gridModel="cityList"        
        rowNum="%{rows}"
        rownumbers="true"  
        altRows ="true"
        altClass = "even"


    >
        <sjg:gridColumn  name="id" index="id" title="ID" formatter="integer" sortable="true"/>
        <sjg:gridColumn name="name" index="name" title="Name" sortable="true"/>
        <sjg:gridColumn name="state_Code" index="state_Code" title="state_Code" sortable="true"/>

    </sjg:grid>
```

I have set the option

```
altRows ="true"
altClass = "even"
```

it generate the class even in all even rows. But i also want to insert odd class in odd rows. How it could be possible?

Comment: a code shot how you did this will help other to give you a better answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the underlying jquery datagrid directly found here: http://www.trirand.com/blog/

Figure out how to use the struts2-json-plugin for ajax and you'll be miles ahead.

As a web programmer you must know JS.

That aside... You are aware that you have set "altClass" but you never set "cssClass" that could be an issue?  Consult the documentation on this tag library here: http://code.google.com/p/struts2-jquery/wiki/GridTag#Using_Tags_to_render_the_Grid

Comment: I can't help my self I've been going on a "I hate ajax-tag-libraries offensive", at the risk of being... well offensive.

Comment: i tried myself these libraries and ended up learning jquery and using it simply :)